# how to make the NSNotification heard by the specific observer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to develop a cloud storage app and I want to achieve that user can  move a file or folder to another folder.

```
-(void)setUpNote{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MoveCopypopViewClicked:) name:@"MoveCopypopViewClickedNotification" object:nil];
}
```

I set a mark thisIsOnTop to mark the view which is on the top.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
self.thisIsOnTop = YES;

[super viewWillAppear:YES];

self.myPopView = [[MoveCopyPopView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenH, screenW, bottomH)];

[HBKeyWindow addSubview:self.myPopView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.myPopView.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenH - bottomH, screenW, bottomH);
}];
[self setupRefresh];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
self.thisIsOnTop = NO;
if (self.tableViewStatus == 1) {
    //[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
    self.tableViewStatus = 0;
    [self disapperPopView];
}
}

-(void)MoveCopypopViewClicked:(NSNotification *)text{
NSDictionary * dict = text.userInfo;
NSString * btnClicked = [dict objectForKey:@"btnClicked"];
self.mycurrentPOPBtnClicked = btnClicked;

if ([self.myChooseType isEqualToString:@"file"]) {
    if ([btnClicked isEqualToString:@"CreateFolderBtnClicked"]) {

        [self showNewFolderView];

    }else if ([btnClicked isEqualToString:@"ConfirmBtnClicked"]){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MoveCopypopViewClickedNotification" object:nil userInfo:self.prepareToPushFolderID];

        for (UIViewController *temp in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
            if ([temp isKindOfClass:[MyDesignTableViewController class]]) {
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:temp animated:YES];
            }
        }

        [self disapperPopView];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView.mj_header beginRefreshing];
    }
}else if ([self.myChooseType isEqualToString:@"folder"]){
    if ([btnClicked isEqualToString:@"CreateFolderBtnClicked"]) {
        [self showNewFolderView];

    }else if ([btnClicked isEqualToString:@"ConfirmBtnClicked"]){

        [self loadMoveFolderRequest];

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];

        [self disapperPopView];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView.mj_header beginRefreshing];
    }
}
}
```

when I moved a file and choose the destination folder and click the confirm-move button ,the file wasn't moved to the folder I choose.

Comment: Where did you call `postNotification` ?

Comment: Why do you have `YES` on this line: `[super viewWillAppear:YES];`?

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code about moving files, nor about notifications.

Comment: This is a company app, and I edit the code at the base of others.

Comment: `setupNote ` was called in the `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually post the notification in order for the 'observer' to activate.

EDIT:

Note that if you want to receive the folderID in loadMoveRequest method, then it should be the 'selector' in addObserver like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadMoveRequest:) name:@"MoveCopypopViewClickedNotification" object:nil];
```

The you post the notification and pass the folderID:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MoveCopypopViewClickedNotification" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:folderID] forKey:@"folderID"]];
```

In case you need to pass some data specific to the notification, you could do so by setting a `NSDictionary` to `userInfo` instead of passing `nil`.

Finally implement the loadMoveRequest: method like so:

```
- (void)loadMoveRequest:(NSNotification *notification) {

    NSInteger folderId = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"folderID"] integerValue];

}
```

Comment: When I click the confirm button I want the current viewController's folderID to pass to the `loadMoveRequest`

Comment: What type is the folderID property? You can pass the folderID in a Dictionary and set it as the userInfo. If its an integer, you can pass it wrapped in an NSNumber like so: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:folderID] forKey:@"folderID"]; Set this as the 'userInfo'

Comment: Note that if you want to receive the folderID in loadMoveRequest method, then it should be the 'selector' in addObserver like so:

Comment: `loadMoveRequest` is a method that connect the backend api, it receives the `folderId` of the destination folder where the file will be moved to ,and it  also receives the `fileID`.

Comment: Ok, so after you receive the fileID you can post the notification. Just make sure that the method in which you want to do something with the 'fileID' is the selector for the notification in addObserver method. That method can then access the fileID like i've shown in the code above.

Comment: @Matrix You can also pass the folderID in similar manner as an additional object in the userInfo dictionary. Check the ```dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:``` method of ```NSDictionary``` by referring to Apple's developer documentation

Comment: It shows the debug error message `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MoveTableViewController loadMoveCell]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9089e8c9f0'`

Comment: It seems to me that this error is due to something else related to a table view controller in your project. Mostly this happens because the table view controller does not implement the ```loadMoveCell``` method. I would suggest that you ask a new question for this issue since your original question is regarding notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle observer as follows in the class/viewcontroller in which you have written the function to move files;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MoveCopypopViewClicked:) name:@"MoveCopypopViewClickedNotification" object:nil];
```

Then you have to write function with the name `MoveCopypopViewClicked` which will have code to move the files in that class/viewcontroler.

Then you need to trigger the notification as follows;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MoveCopypopViewClickedNotification" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

And to pass values with this notification, you can pass **NSDictionary** to **userInfo**

Comment: I  have edited the `MoveCopypopViewClicked`, the debug error shows that `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b40c220'`

Comment: You have not passed proper NSDictionary in Notification. It says that the value you have passed is of  **NSCFConstantString** type